# prevent matplotlib from rebasing my axes at zero

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have a pandas time series:

```
timeSeries
2010-01-16 02:00:00    512450
2010-01-16 02:00:01    512450
2010-01-16 02:00:02    512450
2010-01-16 02:00:03    512450
...
```

I want to plot it, so I do:

```
timeSeries.plot()
```

But when I do this I get a plot that has a y-axis that starts at 0. At the top of the chart matplotlib helpfully tells me that by 0 it means "+5.1245e5". This subtraction makes it hard to read the plot.

Edit: Setting `ylim` doesn't help because the limits are actually set correctly. Similarly with `yticks`.

How can I stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out order matters. `useOffset=False` needs to be set before the `plot` command is called. E.g.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set `useOffset=False`.  One way to set it is:

```
ax = timeSeries.plot()
ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False)
```

Comment: it worked, but only if I did it before the `plot()` call. Edited your answer to do this.